# Alternatives to the "Partition By" Statement in SQL

Tags: sql

If I am interested in selecting records that have the largest value in each group of duplicate records (and some general conditions), I normally do this with the following SQL code:

```
select a.id, a.col2, b.col3
from (select id, col2, col3,
rank() over (partition by id order by col2 desc, col3 desc) as r1 from my_table where col2 > 5 and col3 > 5) a
where a.r1 =1
```

I am interested in learning alternate ways to do this.

- Are there other popular ways to do this in (netezza) SQL?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.col2, t1.col3
FROM my_table t1
WHERE t1.col2 > 5 AND t1.col3 > 5
  AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM my_table t2
            WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.col2 > 5 AND t2.col3 > 5
              AND (t2.col2 > t1.col2 OR (t2.col2 = t1.col2 AND t2.col3 > t1.col3))
          );
```

Or, if you use a CTE to preselect from the table:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, col2, col3
  FROM my_table
  WHERE col2 > 5 AND col3 > 5
)
SELECT c1.*
FROM cte c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM cte c2
            WHERE c2.id = c1.id 
              AND (c2.col2 > c1.col2 OR (c2.col2 = c1.col2 AND c2.col3 > c1.col3))
          );
```

Depending on the requirement, the `WHERE` clause inside the subquery may be a lot more complex. This is one of the reasons that, if you can, you should use a window function.

Comment: Thank you! In Query 1 - why do you need "AND NOT EXISTS"?

Comment: in Query 2  - why do you need the CTE?

Comment: @antonoyaro8 the query returns a row only if there is no other row with the same id and greater col2 (or if col2 is the same then with greater col3). This is what NOT EXISTS does. In the 2nd query, the cte filters the table with the rows of the table with col2> 5 and col3>5 and in the main query there is no need to check this condition.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to write Query 2 without using CTE's? Thanks!

Comment: @antonoyaro8 the 2nd query without a cte is the 1st query.